How to handle “next Monday” in reported speech?
In reported speech we change next week to either

the next week,
the following week,
the week after, or
the week later.

But how should we handle next Monday?
Is there some way of changing it, or do we just leave it the way it is?

I marked  "next Monda" not "this next Monday".

Ah, I guess your unclear typing led me astray. I have edited your question accordingly.

Why not answer it then, too? I think it isreally easy for a native to tell me the answer. Btw thanks for editing

As with so much else, the answer depends greatly on context. What is the situation, what did the speaker of the reported speech mean, and what does the speaker who’s reporting the speech mean?

"I will do it tomorrow" if we know it was stated on Monday and now is Tuesday we  can he said he would do it today. Now if we don't really know when it was we cam simple change tomorrow to the next day. What if someone saya I will do it next Monday. We don't really remeber when it was. What then? Do we  somehow change next Monday as we do with tomorrow?

@Adam do you mean like the pub notice "free beer tomorrow"? 'Tomorrow' in Spanish is mañana which can take on a broader meaning than 'next day'.

Direct: "I'll come next Monday". Indirect: He said he'd come the following Monday. If you know that's okay with week (or month, year, etc.) why would you think daynames might not follow the same pattern? btw - I don't like your rephrase #3 one bit, and your #4 is just ungrammatical

@FumbleFingers I gave 4 options and for example "the Monday after or later" doesm't sound right. What do you think?

You misunderstood the context. He said he'd come the Monday after or later is fine (the Monday after is precisely interchangeable with the following Monday; he wouldn't come earlier, but maybe later). It's nonsensical to split that into two separate alternatives with their own numbers! Note that in the "indirect" versions, words like today, tomorrow,... are inherently ambiguous in such contexts (are they relative to when he spoke, or the later reporting?). But the morning after and the following weekend are *always relative to when he spoke, so they're never ambiguous.

...or later there is "truncated" from ...or later than the following Monday

@FumbleFingers. What about this one "I will do it in 4 days". My teacher says that we just leave it but in my opinion we should either say "in the following or next 4 days" or " in the 4 days later or after". How should it be done?

Please stop blindly repeating the words "in the following or" until you understand what they mean in context. Also stop randomly moving words around and asking what the (often, nonsense) permutation means. Explain using as many words as necessary what meaning you want to convey, and we'll tell you whether your best guess does that properly or not.

Just out of interest - is "your teacher" in fact chatgpt or similar?

Real person. With bones and so on haha.

Well, putting aside my personal preference against your example #3 and the inexplicable glitch leading to #4, your teacher correctly showed you how to handle week in direct / reported speech (examples #1 and #2). The problems with #3 & #4 are because they should be a week after / later, which I suppose is because you're still struggling with definite / indefinite articles. I still don't understand why you thought daynames (or indeed, month, year, etc.) would be different to week, but hopefully you see now that the same approach works for all.

It depends on the time from which you are reporting the speech.
So if on Wednesday 1st May, someone says "next Monday" they mean Monday 6th May.
If you are reporting their speech on Thursday 2nd May, you might use "next Monday" to refer to the 6th.  If you are reporting their speech on Tuesday 14th May, you might say "last Monday".  If you are reporting their speech on Monday 6th May, you might say "today"
The point being, that you report the time just as you would report any time, it is relative your the current time, not to the time when the person was speaking.

He said, "I will start work next Monday".


He said that he'd start work today.  (reported on Monday)

There are expressions that would always work, like "Monday of the following week", but in context these are unlikely to be the most idiomatic.

I mean, when someone says "I will do it tomorrow" and it was stated let's say many years ago we don't really know when then we csn say " the next day". I want to  what we do with "next Monday" in the same situation, leave it or there is some expression?

Yes. @Adam, suppose that on Sunday the 26th John says, “I’ll see you next Monday.” A native speaker would interpret that to mean the Monday eight days thence, not the very next day (Monday the 27th). If John had said it on Friday the 24th, then a native speaker might interpret it to mean Monday the 27th, but probably not. The latest date on which he could say it and be unambiguously understood to mean Monday the 27th is Monday the 20th.

"Monday of the following week" is usually said as "Monday week" or "A week on Monday".

@WeatherVane: "I'll come [on] Monday week" is definitely British. Until I just produced that NGram usage chart, I kinda thought it was "dialectal" (specifically, my UK SE dialect). But that chart shows it to be essentially a late Victorian "affectation". It doesn't mean next Monday, though - it means the one a week after that.

As expected, on Friday week is / was more common than ...Monday. That's despite the fact that I'll do it on Monday is far more common I'll do it on Friday. Reason being it's obvious which Friday you mean (not the one just coming up in this week. But people unfamiliar with the usage mistakenly think any day within "next week" (after the weekend) matches.

Is the part where the answer says "June" supposed to say "June"?

The meaning of "next Monday" etc is inconsistent in native speech. It may refer to the Monday of the following week or the next Monday to occur. This is necessarily a matter of dialect. In my family (all speakers of approximately the same dialect) there were frequent misunderstandings for this reason; similarly with friends. Be cautious about usage.

@FrancisDavey: I don't understand how "next Monday" can be ambiguous at time of speaking. I can only see ambiguity in He said he'd come next Monday (could be relative to time of him speaking OR time of later reporting). Plenty of people would misunderstand He said he'd come Monday week if they heard it, but Americans would very rarely encounter that one anyway, as pointed out above. But next Monday is always the first Monday after time of speaking, which is obviously always next week (but certainly not in 1 or 2 days time, if spoken at the weekend! :)

@FumbleFingers At least amongst British English speakers, "next Monday" said on a Sunday could mean either "tomorrow" or the Monday following that. Monday is probably the least troublesome ("next Friday" being much worse) but still the problem exists. My mother tends to the second meaning, some of her sisters tend the other way as do I. Grandparents etc and friends vary too. I am glad you haven't encountered the ambiguity, but it exists amongst native speakers.

@FrancisDavey: I venture to suggest no native speaker would ever say I'll see you next Monday on a Sunday, when what they mean is I'll see you tomorrow.

@FumbleFingers it would be  nice if that was true. I can think back to lots of frustrating conversations as a child for counter-examples.

@FrancisDavey: Well, yes. I think my comment about on Friday week being much more common than on Monday week, a relationship that reverses with I'll do it on Monday being more common that I'll do it on Friday hinges on people tending to avoid the useful but potentially less familiar " week" form in contexts where it might be misunderstood.

Australian here. When someone says "next ", I will assume they mean "next week " because otherwise they would have said "this " or simply "". To my knowledge, this is common in Australia, and annoys everyone who interprets it as "[the] next " instead of "next [week] ". It definitely causes confusion. (Rural Australians are mostly likely to use " week" for the same thing)

Forms 1–3 are all valid.

the next Monday
the following Monday
the Monday after

"The Monday later" doesn't work, but I'd argue it doesn't entirely work with 'week' either. 'Later' is usually used with durations, so a week later is more idiomatic, and is syntactically not quite identical to the others: 'week' is a measure of time, not a group of days on the calendar. That's why we can't use 'Monday' the same way.

How would you report 'in 4 days or in 10 hours"?

@Adam No change. "He said he would start the job in 4 days."

The same way or just leave please show?

But on one site I saw they changed "in one hour to one hour later" why is that, then?

@Adam That would be necessary in direct past tense: "He started the job 4 days later." In reported speech either is fine.

But which are fine? What about 4 days after the following 4 days and the next 4 days? Are the fine too?

@Adam Sorry, can you rephrase? I don't understand.

I will do it in 4 days.  He says he would do it a)4 days after b)4 days later c) the following 4 days d) the next 4 days

@Adam A and B correspond to "I will start it 4 days from now" (which is a valid interpretation of "I will do it in 4 days") and C and D correspond to "I will work on it for 4 days starting now" (which is different).

So I could use c and d when I report this kind of sentence  I will do it for 4 days. Altought in any number days or for any number don't neeed to be reported right?

@Adam Right, those work the same whether reported or direct.

What about this  "next month" we can change to "the next month" the following month" or "the month after or later" but "next two months" would be only changed to "two months after or later" but not "two following months or two next months" right?
